# Can't get Javascript to set text

Tags: javascript

I see examples for this all over, but for some reason, mine isn't working. I have a textbox that is added dynamically if a certain value is selected in a select list.

The part where the field shows up is working, but I am also trying to add some text to the box, which I can't get to work. I'm also trying to use JS to select the text once it's entered - but haven't gotten that far yet!

Is there something blatantly wrong with this?

```
function showBox() {
  if (document.getElementById("ctl00_Content_WhereFound").value == "Other" || document.getElementById("ctl00_Content_WhereFound").value == "Friend/Employee Referral") 
  {
    document.getElementById('ctl00_Content_WhereDetails').style.display = "inline";
    if (document.getElementById("ctl00_Content_WhereFound").value == "Other") {
      document.getElementById('ctl00_Content_WhereDetails').innerHTML += 'Enter Other';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('ctl00_Content_WhereDetails').innerText += "Enter Referral";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing looks wrong at first glance. Perhaps you could set up an example that shows the problem? [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com)

Comment: What kind of element is `ctl00_Content_WhereDetails`? If it is a form field you must use `value` and not `innerHTML` or `innerText`. (`innerText` is in any case IE-only and `innerHTML+=` should be avoided as it destroys and re-parses any element content).

Comment: @bobince - it's a asp.net textbox - The name you see is what is created by .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

```
function showBox()
{
    $Found = document.getElementById("ctl00_Content_WhereFound");
    $Where = document.getElementById('ctl00_Content_WhereDetails');

    if($Found.value == "Other" || $Found.value == "Friend/Employee Referral")
    {
        $Where.style.display = "inline";
        if($Where.value == "Other")
        {
            $Where.value = 'Enter Other';
        }else
        {
             $Where.value = "Enter Referral";
        }
    }
}
```

You can always assign elements to variables to shorten your code.

Comment: @RoberPitt - the second if should read "if($found.value == "Other") but +1 to you for providing the right answer AND cleaning up my crappy code! :)

Comment: its not crappy, its the fact that you still have more to learn that's all. my code is probably crappy to other members :)

Answer (score 4):

First thing I noticed was that you used 'innerHTML' in your if clause and 'innerText' in your else clause.  Was that on purpose? They do different things...

It's a pain, but it might be worth using the `document.createElement()` etc functions to build/modify the dynamic content.

I've had trouble with similar stuff... in general, using the DOM functions rather than innerHTML often fixes it, though it is significantly more verbose.  JQuery has some very helpful functions for this.

Comment: I was trying different things to see if I could get either to work.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you're attempting to make a change to Asp.Net rendered controls. Make sure you have the actual id of the controls formatted correctly. Typically the UniqueID is formatted like `ctl00_Content_WhereFound` but the ClientID is formatted `ctl00$Content$WhereFound`.

Comment: `id` is rendered with underscores, `name` is rendered with $

Answer (score 1):

`innerText` isn't supported by at least Firefox. Is there a reason you can't use `innerHTML` in both cases?

Also, you might want to store the element references to make your code cleaner and faster:

```
function showBox() {
  var eFound = document.getElementById("ctl00_Content_WhereFound");
  if (eFound.value == "Other" || eFound.value == "Friend/Employee Referral") 
  {
    var eDetails = document.getElementById('ctl00_Content_WhereDetails');
    eDetails.style.display = "inline";
    if (eFound.value == "Other") {
      eDetails.innerHTML += 'Enter Other';
    } else {
      eDetails.innerHTML += "Enter Referral";
    }
  }
}
```